# How to calculate average of numbers from a text input file?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an input file which looks as follows:

```
2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62
4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64
6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66
8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68
10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67 70
```

How do I find the average of all these numbers in Spark? 
I have been able to write the code till this point.

```
val x1 = input.map( (value:String)=> value.split(" ") )
```

(input is the hdfs location of the input textfile containing all the numbers)

Comment: are you looking to find average of all the numbers or average of line by line?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a solution using Spark SQL's Dataset API or Spark Core's RDD API. I'd strongly recommend using Spark SQL.

---

Let's assume the following `lines` dataset.

```
val lines = spark.read.text("input.txt").toDF("line")
scala> lines.show(truncate = false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|line                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62   |
|4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64  |
|6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66  |
|8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68 |
|10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67 70|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(you called the above dataset `input`, but `lines` made more sense -- sorry for confusion).

With that, you simply `split` the lines into "numbers", i.e. string literals.

```
val numArrays = lines.withColumn("nums", split($"line", "\\s+"))
scala> numArrays.printSchema
root
 |-- line: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nums: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

scala> numArrays.select("nums").show(truncate = false)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|nums                                                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59, 62]   |
|[4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58, 61, 64]  |
|[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66]  |
|[8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59, 62, 65, 68] |
|[10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58, 61, 64, 67, 70]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

One Spark idiom with calculating *a thing* from arrays is to `explode` it first followed by `groupBy`. That may not be the most efficient solution, but that depends on whether the lines are unique (I assume they are) and how large the dataset really is.

```
val ns = numArrays.withColumn("n", explode($"nums"))
scala> ns.show
+--------------------+--------------------+---+
|                line|                nums|  n|
+--------------------+--------------------+---+
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...|  2|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...|  5|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...|  8|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 11|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 14|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 17|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 20|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 23|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 26|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 29|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 32|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 35|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 38|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 41|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 44|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 47|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 50|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 53|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 56|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20...|[2, 5, 8, 11, 14,...| 59|
+--------------------+--------------------+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

With `ns` that has numbers calculating average is a breeze.

```
val avgs = ns.groupBy("line").agg(avg($"n") as "avg")
scala> avgs.show(truncate = false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|line                                                          |avg |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67 70|40.0|
|2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62   |32.0|
|6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66  |36.0|
|8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68 |38.0|
|4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64  |34.0|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----+
```

---

Another solution could be to use a user-defined function and calculate an average directly on arrays. I'd not be surprised if a user-defined function beat the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
 val input= spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///D:/Fast-Nu/input.txt")  // it is local path you can give here hdfs path

 val x1= input.flatMap(_.split("\\s"))       //_.split("\\s") is same as (x=>x.split("\\s")) 
 val x2 = x1.map(_.toInt)                   // _.toInt same as x=>x.toInt

 val agg = x2.aggregate((0,0))(
 (x,value)=>(x._1+value,x._2+1),
 (x1,x2)=> (x1._1+x2._1, x1._2+x2._2 ) )

 val average = agg._1/agg._2.toDouble
 println(average)
```

**Solution 2**

```
val input= spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///D:/Fast-Nu/input.txt")    // it is local path you can give here hdfs path

val x1= input.flatMap(_.split("\\s"))
val x2 = x1.map(_.toInt)

val avg = x2.mean
println(avg)
```

**Solution 3**

```
val input= spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///D:/Fast-Nu/input.txt")      // it is local path you can give here hdfs path

val x1= input.flatMap(_.split("\\s"))
val x2 = x1.map(_.toInt)

val x3 = x2.map(x=>(x,1)).reduce((x,y)=>(x._1+y._1, x._2+y._2))
val avg= x3._1.toDouble/x3._2.toDouble

println(avg)
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres something simpler is all the records are space separated in one line. If the numbers are in separate line to can make changes accordingly.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", " ")
val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("file_path", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
val inputRdd = input.map { case (_, text) => text.toString.toLong}
```

This will create an rdd with each number as one element, next,

```
val tup = inputRdd
      .map((_, 1L))
      .reduce(reducer)

val avg = tup._1/ tup._2
```

Where reducer is,

```
def reducer(a: (Long, Long), b: (Long, Long)): (Long, Long) = (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2)
```

the avg is your result.

Hope this helps, cheers.